# How can I get the commit date associated with an issue using SonarQube Web Service API or any plugins

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-5.0

Is there a way to get the commit date associated with an issue using SonarQube Web Service API?

My Sonar Server details

SonarQube Version - 5.2
Sonar-Runner      - 2.4
Project SCM Plugin - sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.1

I am sending weekly reports on new violations to Project Managers. I use WebService API to get all new (OPEN) issues created between two dates. But some times new issues are reported which will have very old commit date like an year before. We have started sonar analysis on our project recently. Ours is a huge project with a lot of legacy code. So we have decided to concentrate on new code.

Getting issues related to old commit is creating a lot of problems. My plan is to get all issues through Web service call, then and close all issues which have commit dates before a certain date. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, and the issues with old commit dates aren't as much of a red herring as you think they are. Consider the rule "Methods should not have too many lines" with a threshold of 3:

```
public void doSomething() {  // commit 1/1
  a();  // commit 1/1
  b();  // commit 1/1
  c();  // commit 1/1
}  // commit 1/1
```

At this point, the method is fine, and no issue is raised. Then on 12/12, I add a line:

```
public void doSomething() {  // commit 1/1  Issue raised here on 12/12
  a();  // commit 1/1
  b();  // commit 1/1
  c();  // commit 1/1
  d();  // commit 12/12
}  // commit 1/1
```

My point is that those new issues you're seeing on old lines are valid and belong in your reports. They'll just take a little more digging to get at.

Comment: yes, the scenario you explained is correct. But I have got a different case.

Comment: public void doSomething() {  // commit 1/1  Issue raised here on 12/12
  a();  // commit 1/1
  b();  // commit 1/1
  c();  // commit 1/1
  d();  // commit 1/1
}  // commit 1/. I have all these lines on 1/1 and it didn't get detected on my sonar analysis even if the bad code was present there already. But after an year somebody made a commit on the same file which is no where related to the method doSomething(). Now in the next analysis the old issue is getting reported, even if nobody touched any lines related to it.

Comment: Hmm. You may want to raise this in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)